# How to Materialize a Big Query Table from a View using CLI (bq Command)?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, etl, business-intelligence

I am looking for a way to materialize a table in Google BigQuery from an existing view which queries the latest version of data from the underlying table. I currently have the following which works quite well from the BigQuery UI.

```
CREATE TABLE `my-data-infra.facebook_leads_ads.facebook_leads_tmp`
PARTITION BY DATE(created_time)
AS SELECT * FROM `my-data-infra.facebook_leads_ads.facebook_leads_view`;

DROP TABLE `my-data-infra.facebook_leads_ads.facebook_leads`;

CREATE TABLE `my-data-infra.facebook_leads_ads.facebook_leads`
PARTITION BY DATE(created_time)
AS SELECT *
FROM `my-data-infra.facebook_leads_ads.facebook_leads_tmp`;

DROP TABLE `my-data-infra.facebook_leads_ads.facebook_leads_tmp`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bq query` to execute queries in the CLI. When running queries from the [bq command-line tool](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/bq-command-line-tool#running_queries_from_the) developed in Google Cloud console, do the following:

1. Include the query in a bq query command as follows: `bq query --use_legacy_sql=false 'QUERY'`. Replace `QUERY` with your query.
2. Replace any single quotes (') in the query with double quotes (").
3. Remove comments from the query.

Keep in mind that [Standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax) is the default query syntax in BigQuery.

For a complete reference of all bq commands and flags, see the [bq command-line tool reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/bq-cli-reference).